# Gradle Support Missing in IntelliJ IDEA's "New Project" Wizard

Tags: scala, gradle, intellij-idea

I recently encountered an issue while trying to create a new project using Gradle with Scala in IntelliJ IDEA. I noticed that the Gradle option is missing from the "New Project" wizard, making it difficult for me to set up a Gradle-based Scala project directly.
I would like to know if there are any alternatives or workarounds to create a Gradle project with Scala in IntelliJ IDEA.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBKWP.png)

I tried reinstalling the IDE and reinstalling Gradle plugins,but it didn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got an answer from JB Support:

"Thank you for reporting this!
IDEA currently only suggests sbt and its' Native Build System for Scala Projects.
As a workaround you can create a Gradle-based Scala Project from the Command Prompt using gradle init command, as described in Gradle documentation.
There is also an existing Issue SCL-20408 in the Scala section of YouTrack, that describes a very similar problem: I would suggest to upvote it to raise its' priority for the developers and leave a comment so they add Gradle option for the New Projects as well as New Modules."

So there is no modules for do this with Scala today.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-gradle.html), Gradle and Gradle Extension plugins are required.

Please check if you have them installed and enabled. If not - install, enable and restart the IDE.

If it doesn't help try delete `disabled_plugins.txt` from [IDE config directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#clean-up-old-ide-dirs)